# Protect Linux based virtual machine from cracking or illegal copy

Tags: licensing, virtual-machine, redhat, esxi

I have developed an application and made a virtual appliance via installing it on RedHat Linux and present that to my customer as an OVA or OVF files.

I go to customers site and deploy OVA file on ESX or VCenter, bring the machine up and read UDI code generated and related via Virtual appliance that always is unique, then I use that UDI and generate a license specified to just that Virtual appliance and import it to the system.

But the problem is here that some dummy customers boot the machine with Live Linux and change or edit some  files to deactivate the licensing requirement  or they get a OVF from current licensed version and use that many times on other sites and they will be able to use the app as many as times as they need without any payment.

Do I need to prevent the virtual machine from booting the Live Linux or when it realize that Virtual machine get copied or cloned from another Hypervyzor?

Do I have to solve this on VmWare side or should I be looking for a solution on Redhat OS itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bakuriu The only way is to crypt your Disk operating system using LUKS, be aware to store your decrypt password in mind , in a safe place , there is no way to retrieve it.

Comment: would you please explain a little more??

Comment: @Bakuriu So, you have to encrypt the data volume after you installed you base Os system, this is more safely more simple. Check this link  [link]http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/. Be carefull when Luks ask you the password there is no return, the password is not recoverable.